# I can't seem to get local storage working

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

My code is not working when I try to save and load a value. I looked this up multiple times with no definitive answers. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
var1 = 1

function save() {
  localStorage.setItem("var1", string(var1));
}
function load() {
  var1 = localStorage.getItem("var1");
}
function up() {
  var1 += 1
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = var1
}
```

```html
<p id="test">1</p><br>
<button onclick="up()">up1</button>
<button onclick="save()">save</button>
<button onclick="load()">load</button>
```

Comment: i use github mostly for this kind of stuff

Comment: Do you want to store number or string?

Comment: i want to store the number

Comment: what is the function `string` in `string(var1)`? Have you done debugging 101? i.e. check the browser **developer** tools console for errors?

Answer (score 2):

LocalStorage store data in key-value format and value are stored as string.

To convert int to string, you can use `toString()`.
Also, while  getting the element from the localStorage, you will get string which you need to convert to int.

Try the below code, it won't work on StackOverflow as it is sandboxed.

```js
var1 = 1

function save() {
  localStorage.setItem("var1", var1.toString());
}

function load() {
  var1 = +localStorage.getItem("var1");
}

function up() {
  var1 += 1
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = var1
}
```

```html
<p id="test">1</p><br>
<button onclick="up()">up1</button>
<button onclick="save()">save</button>
<button onclick="load()">load</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to convert to a string when you're storing it, but you should convert it back to an integer when you get it back out of storage.

```js
function save() {
    localStorage.setItem("var1", var1);
}

function load() {
    var1 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("var1"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In  local storage the keys can be strings or integers, but the values are always strings.So inside `load` function try to convert the retrieved string to number. Else instead of adding it will string concatenation.For example `8+1` will `81` instead of `9`.

Also there is no `body` tag in your DOM

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="test">1</p><br>
  <button onclick="up()">up1</button>
  <button onclick="save()">save</button>
  <button onclick="load()">load</button>
  <script>
    var var1 = 1;

    function save() {
      console.log(var1)
      localStorage.setItem("var1", var1);
    }

    function load() {
      //using unary operator to convert string to number
      var1 = +localStorage.getItem("var1");
      console.log(typeof var1)
    }

    function up() {
      var1 += 1;
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = var1;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```